# Loop Through Nested Array in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, loops

I want to loop through this json file, and print the `attendantName` for each store. I am able to print the key and value, and I am able to print the first attendant in the arrays of attendants.  But I need to print all the attendants in the array.  I think I need a nested loop.  How can I do this? This is what I have so far.

script.js

```
var data;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'js/tender-total-data.json');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (request.status === 200 && request.readyState === 4) {
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    $.each(data.stores, function(key, val){
      console.log("The key is: ", key, "The value is; ", val);
      console.log("Attendant Name: ", (val.attendants[0].attendantName));
      console.log(val.storeId);
    })

  }
};

request.send();
```

tender-total-data.json

```
{
  "stores": [
        {
        "storeName": "Master Bistro",
        "storeId": "3046",
        "attendants": [
            {
            "attendantName": "Janis Joplin",
            "attendantId": "9784526",
            "total": 2000,
            "tenderTotal": {
                "Cash": 500,
                "TC": 0,
                "UOD": 500,
                "MC": 250,
                "VI": 250,
                "AX": 250,
                "DI": 250,
                "JC": 0,
                "DC": 0,
                "UOP": 0,
                "GN": 0,
                "UOGC": 0,
                "HOTEL": 0,
                "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            },
            {
            "attendantName": "David Bowie",
            "attendantId": "2589456",
            "total": 14675,
            "tenderTotal": {
                "Cash": 175,
                "TC": 0,
                "UOD": 100,
                "MC": 9500,
                "VI": 3500,
                "AX": 550,
                "DI": 850,
                "JC": 0,
                "DC": 0,
                "UOP": 0,
                "GN": 0,
                "UOGC": 0,
                "HOTEL": 0,
                "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            },
            {
            "attendantName": "Michael Jackson",
            "attendantId": "5478264",
            "total": 15599,
                "tenderTotal": {
                    "Cash": 250,
                    "TC": 0,
                    "UOD": 80,
                    "MC": 5624,
                    "VI": 6895,
                    "AX": 2500,
                    "DI": 250,
                    "JC": 0,
                    "DC": 0,
                    "UOP": 0,
                    "GN": 0,
                    "UOGC": 0,
                    "HOTEL": 0,
                    "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            }
        ],
            "message": "Store totals for 08/20/2018"
    },{

        "storeName": "The Master  Marketplace",
        "storeId": "3047",
        "attendants": [
            {
                "attendantName": "Dirk Novitski",
                "attendantId": "9784527",
                "total": 2000,
                "tenderTotal": {
                    "Cash": 500,
                    "TC": 0,
                    "UOD": 500,
                    "MC": 250,
                    "VI": 250,
                    "AX": 250,
                    "DI": 250,
                    "JC": 0,
                    "DC": 0,
                    "UOP": 0,
                    "GN": 0,
                    "UOGC": 0,
                    "HOTEL": 0,
                    "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "attendantName": "Carmello Anthony",
                "attendantId": "2589458",
                "total": 14675,
                "tenderTotal": {
                    "Cash": 175,
                    "TC": 0,
                    "UOD": 100,
                    "MC": 9500,
                    "VI": 3500,
                    "AX": 550,
                    "DI": 850,
                    "JC": 0,
                    "DC": 0,
                    "UOP": 0,
                    "GN": 0,
                    "UOGC": 0,
                    "HOTEL": 0,
                    "NCTNCG": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "attendantName": "Stevie Wonder",
                "attendantId": "5478266",
                "total": 15599,
                "tenderTotal": {
                    "Cash": 250,
                    "TC": 0,
                    "UOD": 80,
                    "MC": 5624,
                    "VI": 6895,
                    "AX": 2500,
                    "DI": 250,
                    "JC": 0,
                    "DC": 0,
                    "UOP": 0,
                    "GN": 0,
                    "UOGC": 0,
                    "HOTEL": 0,
                    "NCTNCG": 0
                }

            }
        ],
            "message": "Store totals for 08/22/2018"
        }
    ]    
}
```

Thanks I appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need another loop, but you can make it a little easier with `.forEach`:

```
var data;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'js/tender-total-data.json');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (request.status === 200 && request.readyState === 4) {
    data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    data.stores.forEach(function(key, val){
      console.log("The key is: ", key, "The value is; ", val);
      val.attendants.forEach(a => console.log("Attendant Name: ",a.attendantName));
      console.log(val.storeId);
    })

  }
};

request.send();
```

Comment: Why not use `.forEach` for the outer loop, too?

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you Luca!

Comment: You can also use a `for...of` loop.

Comment: Yes, all of them are viable options, since you don't seem to use jquery anywhere else, using $.each isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

One `forEach` to iterate `stores` and the second inside to iterate `attendants`

```js
var data = {
  stores: [
    {
      storeName: "Master Bistro",
      storeId: "3046",
      attendants: [
        {
          attendantName: "Janis Joplin",
          attendantId: "9784526",
          total: 2000,
          tenderTotal: {
            Cash: 500,
            TC: 0,
            UOD: 500,
            MC: 250,
            VI: 250,
            AX: 250,
            DI: 250,
            JC: 0,
            DC: 0,
            UOP: 0,
            GN: 0,
            UOGC: 0,
            HOTEL: 0,
            NCTNCG: 0
          }
        },
        {
          attendantName: "David Bowie",
          attendantId: "2589456",
          total: 14675,
          tenderTotal: {
            Cash: 175,
            TC: 0,
            UOD: 100,
            MC: 9500,
            VI: 3500,
            AX: 550,
            DI: 850,
            JC: 0,
            DC: 0,
            UOP: 0,
            GN: 0,
            UOGC: 0,
            HOTEL: 0,
            NCTNCG: 0
          }
        },
        {
          attendantName: "Michael Jackson",
          attendantId: "5478264",
          total: 15599,
          tenderTotal: {
            Cash: 250,
            TC: 0,
            UOD: 80,
            MC: 5624,
            VI: 6895,
            AX: 2500,
            DI: 250,
            JC: 0,
            DC: 0,
            UOP: 0,
            GN: 0,
            UOGC: 0,
            HOTEL: 0,
            NCTNCG: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      message: "Store totals for 08/20/2018"
    },
    {
      storeName: "The Master  Marketplace",
      storeId: "3047",
      attendants: [
        {
          attendantName: "Dirk Novitski",
          attendantId: "9784527",
          total: 2000,
          tenderTotal: {
            Cash: 500,
            TC: 0,
            UOD: 500,
            MC: 250,
            VI: 250,
            AX: 250,
            DI: 250,
            JC: 0,
            DC: 0,
            UOP: 0,
            GN: 0,
            UOGC: 0,
            HOTEL: 0,
            NCTNCG: 0
          }
        },
        {
          attendantName: "Carmello Anthony",
          attendantId: "2589458",
          total: 14675,
          tenderTotal: {
            Cash: 175,
            TC: 0,
            UOD: 100,
            MC: 9500,
            VI: 3500,
            AX: 550,
            DI: 850,
            JC: 0,
            DC: 0,
            UOP: 0,
            GN: 0,
            UOGC: 0,
            HOTEL: 0,
            NCTNCG: 0
          }
        },
        {
          attendantName: "Stevie Wonder",
          attendantId: "5478266",
          total: 15599,
          tenderTotal: {
            Cash: 250,
            TC: 0,
            UOD: 80,
            MC: 5624,
            VI: 6895,
            AX: 2500,
            DI: 250,
            JC: 0,
            DC: 0,
            UOP: 0,
            GN: 0,
            UOGC: 0,
            HOTEL: 0,
            NCTNCG: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      message: "Store totals for 08/22/2018"
    }
  ]
};

data.stores.forEach(o => {
  o.attendants.forEach(n => console.log(n.attendantName));
});
```